# Why is Ant running testclasses defined in a testng.xml in wrong order?

Tags: java, ant, testng

I got the following testng.xml and build.xml:

```
<suite name="My test suite" preserve-order="true">
 <parameter name="a" value="abcd"/>
 <parameter name="b" value="efgh"/>

<test name="testing">
<classes>
   <class name="test.First"/>
   <class name="test.Second">
    <methods>
        <exclude name="method1"/>
    </methods>
   </class>
   <class name="test.Third"/>
   <class name="test.Forth">
        <methods>
            <exclude name="method3"/>
        </methods>
   </class> 
   <class name="test.Fifth"/>
   <class name="test.Sixth"/>
</classes>
```

If I execute the testng.xml inside my IDE the classes are called in order: First, Second,..., Sixth
But if I run the following build.xml with ANT the classes are called in wrong order like this: Sixth, Fourth, Fifth,Second,Third,First. The order changes. I thought that with TestNG this shouldnt be happening?

build.xml:

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="Dummy">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="MyEclipse"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.6"/>
<property name="source" value="1.6"/>
<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="../selenium-server-standalone-2.10.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="testng.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="init" name="build">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}" encoding="iso-8859-1">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<taskdef name="testng"
      classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask"
      classpathref="classpath"/>
<target name="test" depends="build">
    <echo message="running tests"/>
    <testng classpathref="classpath" outputdir="testng_output">
         <xmlfileset dir="bin" includes="testng.xml"/>
    </testng>
</target>
```

Why is the order wrong?

I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Because ordering of XML nodes in your document is not forced when the document is read/transformed into Objects

Comment: the TestNG doc states:"By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file to be run in an unpredictible order, set the preserve-order attribute to false" How can I get this behaviour?

Comment: Then please disregard my irrelevant comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi perhaps you are using two different versions of testng, one that is included by the Eclipse Plugin and another one in your classpath. There was a bug (http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/detail?r=966) on the preserve-order attribute, may be you have the bugged version in your classpath. Try updading the testng version referred by the build.xml script

Comment: I ll take a look at that. My Eclipse plugin for TestNG is version 6.3 (the newest I think)

Comment: I only have the testng.jar and eclipse-testng.jar from the plugin. Switching between those two doesnt change the behaviour :-/

Comment: I tried removing the <pathelement location="testng.jar"/> and ant still executes the tests O_o How can I find out which jar it is using? I dont have that jar in my classpath.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue and if I remove the testng.jar declaration from the build.xml I cannot even run the taks since I got Taskdef TestNGAntTask not found. With testng-6.3.jar on my classpath the execution order of the testng.xml is correct even if I run the build.xml. You must have a testng in your classpath, try to look at the project properties. I run the build.xml tasks from the Eclipse Ant view

Comment: The selenium server jar contains the testng packages which arent equal to the current version how can I exlude those to actually use the current version from the testng.jar?

Comment: try to put the testng jar before the selenium one in the classpath definition of the build.xml some thing like <path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/><pathelement location="testng.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../selenium-server-standalone-2.10.0.jar"/>
    
</path>

Comment: Thx for your help it works now correctly. It really seems as if the testng packages used by selenium are not up to date. So adding a the current testng-6.3.jar solves the issue.

Comment: It looks like you figured it out. FYI, `preserve-order` is set to `true` by default since 6.3.